# Celery beat tasks not executing

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I'm learning periodic tasks in Django with celery beat. But my tasks are not executing.

my `__init__.py` file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app


__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

my `celery.py` file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'new_todo_app.settings')
app = Celery('new_todo_app')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

my `tasks.py` file:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery import shared_task

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')


@shared_task
def progress_bar():
    print("Executed every minute")
```

and my `settings.py` file

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Baku'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True


CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'progress-bar': {
       'task': 'app1.tasks.progress_bar',
       'schedule': 5.0,
    },
}
```

I run celery beat worker by writing:

```
#celery -A new_todo_app beat -l info
```

celery beat starts, but tasks don`t execute.I tried DEBUG logging mode and I get:

```
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%DEBUG
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
[2019-12-04 19:35:24,937: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting default socket timeout to 30
[2019-12-04 19:35:24,938: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2019-12-04 19:35:24,975: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
<ScheduleEntry: progress-bar app1.tasks.progress_bar() <freq: 5.00 seconds>
<ScheduleEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup() <crontab: 0 4 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>
[2019-12-04 19:35:24,975: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 minutes
[2019-12-04 19:35:24,977: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes.
```

I just started learning celery, and feel like maybe something is wrong with my configurations.
Thanks beforehand

Comment: How do you know they are not executing? Everything looks fine to me and the log you show actually shows that.

Comment: @dirkgroten I call `progress_bar` function which is in `tasks.py`, it has `print()` statement, so I can see if it's actualy executed.However wheh I run celery beat, I don't get anything in terminal,  only **beat: Starting...**

Comment: That’s because when the task runs in a different process the print statement goes to stdout which is in the syslog by default. If you look at /var/log/syslog you should see your print statement (assuming you’re on Linux/Unix and you can find amongst all the other stuff in there).  You need to add logging to your celery worker and log to a file. Or just do something useful such as write to the db and you’ll see it.

Comment: @dirkgroten I tried to run celery using `celery -A new_todo_app worker -B -l INFO` and actualy I got outputs from my function as I expected. What is a difference between running celery worker and beat seperately or using `...worker -B` flag?